# Responsive gallery with landscape and portrait images

Tags: php, html, css, image-gallery

I want to have a gallery page that displays a grid of photos.  The sequence of the photos is fairly important, and needs to run in rows from left to right.  In addition, the layout needs to be responsive, with differing numbers of columns according to pages size.  If all the photos are landscape then this isn't a problem.  I'm currently doing this as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbcontainer">
    <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=27; $i++){
            echo '<a class="thumbnail" href="gallery/image.php?image=' . $i . '"><img src="gallery/thumbnails/image_' . $i . '.jpg" width="100%"></a>' . "\n";
        }
    ?>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media all and (min-width: 905px){
    .thumbnail{
        width: 19%;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 904px){
    .thumbnail{
        width: 24%;
    }
}
.thumbcontainer{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.thumbnail{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

The problem is that I want to be able to have portrait images in the grid too that take up two rows of the grid (they will be the same width as the landscape ones and twice the height), while maintaining the responsive nature of the grid.  For example, if L represents landscape and P portrait, and the number represents the image number, then a grid might look like this:

L1   L2   P3   L4

P5   L6   P3   L7

P5   L8   L9   L10

Is there any way to do this?  I've searched everywhere and racked my brains but can't think of a way to do this without prior knowledge of the number of columns/rows required and the position of portrait images in the order.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need javascript, or at least a plugin like isotope::

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html